# How do I find the matrix of a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^3 \longrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ of an orthogonal reflection on a planoe

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So the questions is, " Find the matrix of the linear transformation of n orthogonal projection on the plane $2x-y+z=0$"

I don't know how I should tackle this problem. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: what do the columns of the matrix represent, in terms of the standard basis?

Comment: Do you mean, i should first look at the standard basis and find what the linear transformation does to them?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=(2,-1,1)$.  Then the projection of a vector $v$ on the plane is given by
$$v-\langle v,\frac{n}{\|n\|}\rangle\frac{n}{\|n\|}
=v-\frac{\langle v,n\rangle}{\|n\|^2}n
=v-\frac16\langle v,\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}
\rangle\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
To get the desired matrix replace $v$ by the canonical basis vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You know the normal vector to the plane: $\vec n=(2,-1,1)$. Hence the orthogonal projection $N=(X,Y,Z)$ of a point $M=(x,y,z)$ will lie on the line though $M$ with directing vector $\vec n$ **and**  satisfy the equation of the plane: $2X-Y+Z=0$

Now the parametric representation of the line yields $N=M+t\vec n=(x+2t,y-t,z+t)$.

Can you determine $t$ so that $N$ does lie in the plane, and deduce the coordinates of $N$ in function of those of $M$?